# create team city build template

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I am working with team city in which I am planning in setting several different builds for a number of my projects.

The builds are going to be very similar ie. all run tests, fxcop etc.

Rather than having to go through the steps to configure each build a number of times, it is possible to create a template of configuration then reuse it for the other builds?

Answer (score 3):

TeamCity has this useful feature and it's called the same - `Build Configuration Template`. Read how tho use it [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Configuration+Template).